# Updating pointer using signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am very new to Qt; please help me to solve the problem.

I am using a thread to perform intensive operations in the background. Meanwhile I want to update the UI, so I am using SIGNALS and SLOTS. To update UI I emit a signal and update UI.

Let us consider below sample code,

```
struct sample
{
    QString name;
    QString address;
};

void Update(sample *);

void sampleFunction()
{
    sample a;
    a.name = "Sachin Tendulkar";
    a.address = "India"
    emit Update(&a);
}
```

In the above code we are creating a local object and passing the address of a local object. In the Qt document, it says that when we emit a signal it will be placed in the queue and late it will be delivered to the windows.  Since my object is in local scope it will be delete once it goes out of the scope.

Is there a way to send a pointer in a signal?

Comment: All signal-slot connections are direct (i.e. slot is invoked synchronously inside emit) by default, so it might be OK to pass pointer to local variable. Much better solution is to pass your structure by value, just like MSalters recommends.

Comment: Thanks for your replay,
If it is synchronous, then no problem.  I will use as it is.
In my application structure is not simple as what I have written, it is too complex.

Answer (score 5):

You're insisting on doing the wrong thing, why? Just send the Sample itself:

```
void Update(sample);
//...
sample a("MSalters", "the Netherlands");
emit Update(a);
```

Comment: In general, I'm not a big fan of passing struct's by value - especially when the structs are large or prone to bloat. But in this case you are right, passing by value may be a better way to go. How large is a QString?

Comment: The cost of a straightforward copy ctor will be far exceeded by the cost of a cross-thread signal, and the cost of that in turn is far exceeded by a GUI update. So, this copy doesn't really matter.

Comment: The QString implementation is a ref-counted COW string, so its quite efficient for passing around.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you've determined that this code is a performance bottleneck you would be better to just pass a copy of the object rather than a pointer.

Really, I mean it.

However, if you must use pointers then use a boost::shared_ptr and it will delete itself.

```
void Update(boost::shared_ptr<sample> s);

void sampleFunction()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<sample> a = boost::shared_ptr<sample>(new sample());
    a->name = "Sachin Tendulkar";
    a->address = "India"
    emit Update(a);    
}
```

Comment: You can't use the . operator on a pointer. You meant to say a->name and a->address. Just a nit pick ;-)

Comment: Deleting argument in slot is a bad idea, because if you connect the signal to more than one slot, you'll get segfault. Just send the Sample as value, anything else is premature optimization and adds unnecessary complexity to memory management.

Comment: Agreed.  Deleting in a slow is bad.  Updated answer to use shared_ptr ... but still, really, just pass by value and save yourself pain :)

Comment: [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) since c++11

Comment: It seems that Qt does not used smart pointer. so your suggestion is not Qt native. What's Qt way to manage that?